# Start Activity as Popover view like iPhone

Tags: android-layout, android

I've implemented the simple list of buttons with 
https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction and 
https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D. 

Its working fine with simple static buttons. 

[image]

My requirement is to display the activity in such dialog like **Popoverview Controller** as in iPad. One more thing the **activity must start in Popoverview for tablets only**. 
[image]

Comment: you can use this https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction example. Like QuickAction class in above example you can have your own class which extends PopupWindows and follow QucickAction class Show method. And thats all, you don't need any other classes. I did the same.

Comment: u just try to do here https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView

Answer (score 0):

Check the Themes for the Activity, you might find useful Dialog or Panel themes

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: This will start the activity as a simple dialog.. What I need is like iPhone Popover view.

Comment: Well, you can start it as a panel and position it pointing at the clicked view to open by sending the x and y of the view.

Answer (score 0):

check this library https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView may be it will helpful to you